# How to get an array from string, containing an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to using a regular expression, or otherwise create a function that will convert a string containing the php array of any form, in the real array, which can operate?

For Example:

```
$str = "array(1, array(2), array('key' => 'value'))";
$arr = stringArrayToArray($str);
```

Maybe there is already such an implementation of task?
Or do not bother, but simply to use eval()?

```
$arr = eval("return $str;");
```

Comment: Where is that data coming from? 99% sure this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Answer (score 0):

You can try explode() function.
Try it.

```
<?php 
    $str = "do you love me";
    $arr = explode(' ', $str);

    print_r($arr);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the `array(` with a `[` and `)` with `]`
as shown below:

```
    $str = "array(1, array(2), array('key' => 'value'))";
    $str = str_replace(" ","",str_replace(",","[",$str));
    $str = str_replace(")","",str_replace("array(","[",$str));
    echo $str;
    $arr = explode("[",$str);
    var_dump($arr);

?>
```

this the best I could get.